# Help with choosing the appropriate phrasal verbs

Tags: american-english, phrasal-verbs, spoken-english

How do I say these, could someone please tell me the appropriate phrasal verbs here?
1.  toddlers don't spare their moms even a second.  They **run after her like a tail**

2. They are always **looking** for their moms to feed them, to get anything they want.  (here I want to what phrasal verb would fit here?)

Answer (score 1):

I would choose:

1. Toddlers don't spare their moms even a second. They **trail after her incessantly**.
2. They are always **pestering** their moms to feed them...

"Trail after" means to follow around. "Incessantly" means unceasingly; never-endingly.

"Pestering" means to nag constantly.